# Как отправить POST запрос UrlConnect

Tags: java, android

Всем доброго времени суток! Появилась такая проблема: нужно отправить данные из приложения в PHP файл и получить новые обратно. Нацарапал такой код:

```
try{
            URL url = new URL("http://csgobets.890m.com/api/app_login.php");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("email", String.valueOf(email.getText()));
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("pass", String.valueOf(pass.getText()));
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            try (OutputStream output = urlConnection.getOutputStream()) {
                output.write(query.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            }

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            resultJson = buffer.toString();
            Log.v("json", resultJson);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
            return resultJson;
        }
```

По идее он должен передать в PHP файл методом POST мыло и пароль, но от PHP файла получаю ответ что переменные из суперглобального POST массива равны null. Помогите разобратся где я ошибся, а то ответов по UrlConnect очень мало(
На всякий случай вот тот часть того php файла, которому выполняется запрос:

```
<?php
$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['email'])) { $login = $_POST['email']; if ($login == '') { unset($login);} } //заносим введенный пользователем логин в переменную $login, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
    if (isset($_POST['pass'])) { $password= md5($_POST['pass']); if ($password =='') { unset($password);} }
    //заносим введенный пользователем пароль в переменную $password, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
if (empty($login) or empty($password)) //если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку и останавливаем скрипт
    {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["error"] = "no_data";
    $response["login"] = $login;
    $response["password"] = $password;
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setRequestProperty()` - это метод для установки заголовков, а вам нужно отправить форму в формате `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Посмотрите ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/13486223/2971719